# Have problem using mkfs.btrfs -m single?

Tags: btrfs

Thanks for reading my topic.

When using mkfs.btrfs the default for metadata is dup (duplicate).

Will I have problem if I use mkfs.btrfs -m single?
Users are saying the main use of "-m dup" is for security. Using the backup metada has helped to recover data if problems occur in the file system. Do problems happen more often in or easier in btrfs ?

Thanks for replying.
Have an nice week.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ubuntu 20.04.5 and Kernel 6.00